# About tlsmail with rails = Error - 'no such file to load -- tlsmail.'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sendmail

I have configured smtp gmail for mail sending. It sends mail well, but when try to open script/console, it says no such file to load -- tlsmail and ends. If i comment out the require 'tlsmail' file in environment.rb file, it doesn't send the mail. gem list also shows the tlsmail installed on machine.

Comment: Maybe you are missing a -rrubygems in your RUBYOPT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found that this was just the issue with tlsmail gem not being installed.

`sudo gem install tlsmail`

fixed the issue.

Comment: I don't advise installing the gem as sudo, unless you install ALL your gems as sudo.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Ruby 1.8.7 or greater, you don't need to install smtp_tls gem.
You just need to enable_starttls_auto in your config/environment.rb

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
 :enable_starttls_auto => true,
 :port           => 587,
 :address        => "smtp.gmail.com",
 :domain         => "example.com",
 :user_name      => "user@domain.com",
 :password       => "your_password",
 :authentication => :plain
}
```